# Domain redirect to IP with port iptables

Tags: linux, redirect, dns, iptables, namecheap

I have domain on namecheap and have created subdomain.domain.com and URL redirect to IP:PORT on DNS settings.

But somehow when I make

`telnet IP PORT` request it works

Ouput:

`telnet IP 2002
Trying IP...
Connected to ...
Escape character is '^]'.
???s?"??+s?"Z?2\?v??????????Connection closed by foreign host.`

---

`telnet subdomain.domain.com 2002` doesn't work.

Output:

`` telnet sub.domain.com 2002`
Trying ipofdomain...
telnet: connect to address ipofdomain: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host ``

---

Anyone can shed some light on how to make it work either on namecheap settings or on other server with iptables, perhaps?

Comment: How long ago was the change made? it can take a while for DNS to propogate.

Comment: Also, `doesn't work` doesn't mean much, provide the full output

Comment: DNS settings is set up, namecheap stuff said it is functional and external IP I am connecting to should be setup properly they suggest. Only I don't know how to set up with iptables to allow for example incoming request from  sub.domain.com with port 2002 to redirect/respond with local ip with 2002.

Comment: Looks like you need a simple `A` record, not URL redirect

Comment: How would I set IP on A record? subdomain point to IP should do the work, but how about specific port to specific port?

Comment: The subdomain already point to `IP:PORT`. So just use the subdomain name. No need to add that port as it is already provided.

Comment: As Dusan pointed out, only `A` record is need that will take all TCP requests and forwards to same port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dusan and Kalyana pointed out, it turns out

`sub.domain.com A record to IP` solves the redirection and port resolves itself.

Thank you guys! Hope it will help some in future.

Answer (score 0):

URL redirect works in HTTP layer. Telnet works at TCP layer. When you make a request to subdomain.domain.com via browser or curl you will see a 302 to IP:port.

Comment: So how would I make it TCP layer from namecheap or how can my external IP which pointed to, can handle request to respond through tcp with specific port?

Comment: DNS can only give ips and not port. You can only do application redirect like the HTTP one namecheap does

Comment: ok, where I should fix it, namecheap or external server I am connecting to? I wanted to sub.domain.com:2002 to respond from external server IP:2002 so that I would be able to test with `telnet sub.domain.com 2002` and get same respond as `telnet IP 2002`

Comment: If you add A record for sub.domain.com as IP it should work. No need to add redirect